# I've wiped my partition table using gparted, is there a way to recover my partition?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, gparted

I've wiped my NTFS (windows) partition table using gparted by clicking on "Device->Create Partition Table... and then apply", is there a way to recover my NTFS partition?

I tried using this command `gpart /dev/sda`
I get the following out put:

```
Begin scan...
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
type: 000(0x00)(unused)
size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
type: 000(0x00)(unused)
size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
type: 000(0x00)(unused)
size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
type: 000(0x00)(unused)
size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

What does this output mean? Is there a way I can recover?

Comment: try `testdisk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition table.  Testdisk will read the surface of the disk and attempt to determine where partitions start and end.

Answer (score 7):

There is a possibility to recover the partition table, but it requires 2 conditions be met:

1. You have not rebooted your machine.
2. The drive was in use at the time the table was changed.

How this works is that the kernel keeps the partition layout in memory. If a partition is in use, it needs to know where the partition starts, so it will refuse to reload the new table until it is no longer in use.

How to do this:

Go to `/sys/block/sda`. Inside there you will see a directory for each partition (`sda1`, `sda2`, etc). Inside each of those is a file called `start` and `size` (so `/sys/block/sda/sda1/start`). If you recreate your partition table using these exact same start locations and sizes, you will be fine.

Note that it does not keep the partition type. Linux doesn't care about this information. So after recreating, you will have to remember what the partition type was set to (NTFS or whatever).

---

### Example

#### Original disk:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 8006 MB, 8006926336 bytes, 15638528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ce29c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2         2099200    15638527     6769664   83  Linux
```

```
# mount | grep sdc
/dev/sdc2 on /mnt/tmp type xfs (rw)
```

```
# cat /mnt/tmp/world
hello
```

#### Wiping the partition table

```
# fdisk /dev/sdc
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.22.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-4): 1
Partition 1 is deleted

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 2
Partition 2 is deleted

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 8006 MB, 8006926336 bytes, 15638528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ce29c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

Note that it's still mounted and accessible:

```
# cat /mnt/tmp/world 
hello
```

#### Get the offsets

```
# cd /sys/class/block/sdc

# ls
alignment_offset  device@            events_poll_msecs  power/     ro     slaves/
bdi@              discard_alignment  ext_range          queue/     sdc1/  stat
capability        events             holders/           range      sdc2/  subsystem@
dev               events_async       inflight           removable  size   uevent

# cat sdc1/start
2048

# cat sdc1/size
2097152

# cat sdc2/start
2099200

# cat sdc2/size
13539328
```

#### Restore the partition table

```
# fdisk /dev/sdc
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.22.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-15638527, default 2048): 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-15638527, default 15638527): +2097151
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 1 GiB is set

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 2): 2
First sector (2099200-15638527, default 2099200): 2099200
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2099200-15638527, default 15638527): +13539327
Partition 2 of type Linux and of size 6.5 GiB is set

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 8006 MB, 8006926336 bytes, 15638528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ce29c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2         2099200    15638527     6769664   83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

**!!** Note that when specifying the last sector, we use the size - 1. **!!**

#### Verification

Let's unmount the drive, run `partprobe` to tell the kernel to pick up the new table, then remount and verify we still get to our file.

```
# umount /mnt/tmp/

# partprobe /dev/sdc

# mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/tmp

# cat /mnt/tmp/world 
hello
```

Comment: +1 How I wish I had the opportunity to have tried this at the time.

Answer (score 1):

`parted` has a rescue command that can sniff around for the filesystem's start and length if you know approximately where it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know the dimensions that the NTFS disk, you "might" be able to reset these using fdisk or parted but I think you're out of luck.