# how to reverse the effect of sgdisk -R=/dev/sdb /dev/sda?

Tags: raid, gpt

I accidentally used `sgdisk -R=/dev/sdb /dev/sda` instead of `sgdisk -R=/dev/sda /dev/sdb` after replacing a broken drive in a raid. Can I recover from this or is all data lost now?

Comment: As long as you haven't rebooted, the old partition setup should still be in memory. (Can't you still access your files?) Also, is this a 2-disk RAID1?

Comment: 2-disk raid1 yes, I have not rebooted but I'm in a rescue system and have not mounted the drives.

Comment: Oh... Without the drives mounted, it may not be loaded in memory :-( Check `/proc/partitions` to see if the partitions are there. Otherwise, it's still recoverable, just harder, you need to figure out the old partitioning. There are tools such as `testdisk` to scan the disk and attempt to locate them.

Comment: Partitions are there. I got all the "start" and "size" values and copied them somewhere safe. 

//Edit (+hoping not to break site rules): I feel like handing this over to a professional. Are your interested or recommend someone, derobert?

Now I'll try and go into this direction:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93681/ive-wiped-my-partition-table-using-gparted-is-there-a-way-to-recover-my-partit

Comment: I'm unfortunately not available. I'd suggest asking in chat, but I'm not sure you have enough rep network-wide to join chat :-(

Comment: BTW: when you recreate the partitions, check them with `mdadm -E`. It's possible the tools will try to find the filesystem, not the RAID metadata...

Comment: And, also, if they're still loaded on /dev/sdb, you could create them on /dev/sda, then add them to the mirror and let it mirror. Then fix /dev/sdb once you're sure /dev/sda has a good copy of the data.

Comment: I was able to partially resolve this and created the partitions on sda beacuse the partition info was still in /sys/block/. All data was saved to an external ftp, biggest problems solved. Thanks a lot @derobert 

One follow up question: I have all partitions working on sdb again, raid volumes are clean but unmounted and sdaX is missing everywhere in the raid 1. When I add a partition with `mdadm /dev/md1 -a /dev/sda2` it talks about recovery in /proc/mdstat for a while and then sda2 gets added as a spare. Any ideas about this phenomenon?
`2       8        2        -      spare   /dev/sda2`

Comment: in /proc/mdstat, you see it doing a recovery? I guess check dmesg for errors.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to recover your data. Please describe your solution in an answer to your own question, to help future visitors with a similar problem. You should ask the question about adding a partition to the RAID array separately, since it's a different question.