# I've wiped my partition table using gparted and testdisk did nothing

Tags: data-recovery, data

I've wiped my NTFS partition table using gparted by clicking on "Device->Create Partition Table... and then apply" by accident.

In this topic "[I've wiped my partition table using gparted, is there a way to recover my partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93681/ive-wiped-my-partition-table-using-gparted-is-there-a-way-to-recover-my-partit)" It says I could use testdisk to recover it. I did a "quick search", it found something but couldn't list any files. I have written the found partition structure to the disk. The disk then showed up as a "format needed" disk. I then did a "deeper search" and written the found partition structure to the disk again. But I still get a "format needed" disk.

I really can't lose the data, is there a way to recover the 250Go primary partition ?

PS : when listing the files after the search, testdisk returns "No file found, filesystem may be damaged"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows checkdisk saved my life (I should have used with it before using testdisk). Used "chkdsk E: /F /R" in cmd.